# Idiomatic way to write multi-project builds with .sbt files in sbt 0.13

Tags: scala, sbt

I hear .sbt files have been improved in various ways in 0.13, and that now I can specify multi-project builds in them.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#sbt-format-enhancements mentions that we can now define subprojects in a .sbt file. I also know that multiple .sbt files in the root will be aggregated into a single conceptual file.

What I'd really like, though, is to not pollute my root with a dozen subproject .sbt files. Is there a way I can throw the subproject build.sbt files into their respective subdirectories, keep some common code between them somewhere shared, and then have a root build.sbt for the entire project that aggregates the subprojects? I have a similar setup in .scala files right now but would prefer to use .sbt files if possible.

If that isn't possible, what is the "correct" way to construct large multi-project builds with .sbt files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should already be the case in 0.12 that you can put `.sbt` files in the base directory of a subproject and the settings there will be included in that project's scope.

Code is reused between `.sbt` files by creating a normal `.scala` file in `project/`.  The code in `project/` will be available for use in the `.sbt` files.  The definitions in one `.sbt` are not visible to other `.sbt` files, at least in 0.13.  This is mainly an implementation restriction and it is undetermined whether this will be lifted in future versions.

The default root project will aggregate all subprojects, including those coming from projects defined in `subProject/build.sbt`.

The current difficulty is making it explicit.
For example, the following `build.sbt` in the root directory would define a subproject in `sub/`.
This is a full definition, defining the ID, base directory, etc... for the project.

`<root>/build.sbt`

```
lazy val sub = project
```

However, it cannot reference anything defined in `<sub>/build.sbt`.  (The existence of `sub/build.sbt` is not known until after `<root>/build.sbt` is compiled and evaluated.)
So, to explicitly define what `sub` aggregates, you'd need something like:

`sub/build.sbt`

```
lazy val sub = project.in(file(".")).aggregates(subSub)
//or: lazy val sub = project in file(".") aggregate subSub

lazy val subSub = project
```

However, this duplicates the definition of `sub`.

A possible solution going forward is to make the root definition just a reference, like:

`<root>/build.sbt`

```
lazy val sub = LocalProject("sub")
```

Comment: As of 0.13, I can add a project definition in a .sbt file though. What if I put such a project value in `subproject1/build.sbt` and want to define a root project that aggregates the subproject builds? If values are not visible between .sbt files, it seems tricky to aggregate or to create cross-subproject dependencies.

Comment: Just to clarify, my ultimate goal is to compartmentalize the subprojects as much as possible and to minimize the amount of code that needs to go in the common .scala files. I'll definitely have to keep some common code between the subprojects but would like them to mostly be as independent as possible.

Comment: Updated to address your comments.  The possible solution indicated is not implemented, only a conceptual solution.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. I'll see how much pain I encounter :)

Comment: I guess that with your proposal, those subprojects could also declare dependencies on other subprojects referenced by name.

Comment: Yes, the name would have to be the same as the directory or there would have to be some LocalProject-like type that also accepts the directory.

Comment: Have these guidelines changed at all with the recent updates? AutoPlugins, etc. I wonder if it'd pay to just write up a canonical "this is how you should make big fancy multi-project builds" document. I know there's one in the manual but it tells you more of what you can do than how you _should_ do it.