# Defining plugin dependency between subprojects in SBT?

Tags: sbt

## EDIT:

Since I put up the bounty, I thought I should restate the question

> > How can a SBT project `P`, with two sub-projects `A` and `B`, set up `B` to have a plugin dependency on `A`, which is a SBT plugin?
> >
> > - Giving `P` a plugin dependency on `A` does not work, since `A` depends on other things in `P`, which results in a circular dependency graph
> > - It has to be a plugin dependency, for `A` is a plugin needed to run `B`s test suite.
> > - `dependsOn` doesn't work, because, well, it has to be a plugin dependency
> >
> > I'd like to know either of
> >
> > - How to do this, or
> > - Why this is impossible, and what the next best alternatives are.

EDIT: clarified that it's a plugin-dependency, since build-dependency is ambiguous

Comment: How does your `subB/project/build.sbt` look like? You should also see [How to use plugin in sbt project when only the plugin's sources available?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20794632/1305344).

Comment: It seems to me that that question does not help, for it only goes into how to add a source plugin like `subA` to the root project's build, and not to one of the subprojects like `subB`. I need to be able to add `subA` to `subB`s build and not root because if root depends on `subA` and `subA` is built by root, I have this circular dependency and nothing works

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: try to put stuff in `subB/build.sbt` instead of `subB/project/build.sbt` like you described.

Comment: The problem is that this stuff I'm putting in `subB/project/build.sbt` is a SBT plugin (or at least a reference to `subA`, which is an SBT plugin). AFAICT putting it in `subB/build.sbt` won't do the right thing since it the results of that plugin *need to be visible in `subB/build.sbt`*

Comment: Can you clarify why you need them to both be subprojects of the same parent project? Also does A depend on things that are directly in P or in another subproject?

Comment: I need both to be subprojects of the same parent project so I can run `test` on all of them from the same SBT console. If I was happy separating them into completely separate projects and jumping back and forth manually, I might as well use Bash for my builds (it actually seems like it might be easier than SBT at this point)

Comment: Oh and `A` depends on stuff in another subproject of `P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Jacek said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743545/1305344), it cannot be done as I would like, as a subproject cannot have a SBT plugin that the root project does not. On the other hand, [this discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/sbt$20plugin$20subproject/scala-user/urY2kkHk-Z8/o_y3Yu5geokJ) contains several alternatives, and would no doubt be useful to anyone who comes across this question in the future.

EDIT: Well, in the end the alternatives mentioned (sbt scripted, etc) were hard and clunky to use. My final solution was to just have a separate project (*not* subproject) inside the repo that depends on the original project via it's ivy coordinates, and using bash to publishLocal the first project, going into the second project and running its tests

```
sbt publishLocal; cd test; sbt test; cd ..
```

I always thought the point of something like SBT was to avoid doing this kind of bash gymnastics, but desperate times call for desperate measures...

Answer (score 12):

When you have a multi-project build configuration with *"project P and two sub-projects A and B"* it boils down to the following configuration:

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val A, B = project
```

As per design, ["If a project is not defined for the root directory in the build, sbt creates a default one that aggregates all other projects in the build."](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#default-root-project) It means that you will have an implicit root project, say `P` (but the name is arbitrary):

```
[plugin-project-and-another]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/plugin-project-and-another/
[info]     A
[info]     B
[info]   * plugin-project-and-another
```

That gives us the expected project structure. On to defining plugin dependency between `B` and `A`.

The only way to define a plugin in a SBT project is to use `project` directory that's the `plugins` project's build definition - ["A plugin definition is a project in <main-project>/project/."](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#by-description) It means that the only way to define a plugin dependency on the project `A` is to use the following:

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("org.example" % "example-plugin" % "1.0")

lazy val plugins = project in file(".") dependsOn(file("../A"))
```

In this build configuration, the `plugins` project depends on another SBT project that happens to be our `A` that's in turn a plugin project.

**A/build.sbt**

```
// http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#example-plugin
sbtPlugin := true

name := "example-plugin"

organization := "org.example"

version := "1.0"
```

**A/MyPlugin.scala**

```
import sbt._

object MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    // configuration points, like the built in `version`, `libraryDependencies`, or `compile`
    // by implementing Plugin, these are automatically imported in a user's `build.sbt`
    val newTask = taskKey[Unit]("A new task.")
    val newSetting = settingKey[String]("A new setting.")

    // a group of settings ready to be added to a Project
    // to automatically add them, do
    val newSettings = Seq(
        newSetting := "Hello from plugin",
        newTask := println(newSetting.value)
    )

    // alternatively, by overriding `settings`, they could be automatically added to a Project
    // override val settings = Seq(...)
}
```

The two files - `build.sbt` and `MyPlugin.scala` in the directory `A` - make up the plugin project.

The only missing piece is to define the plugin `A`'s settings for the project `B`.

**B/build.sbt**

```
MyPlugin.newSettings
```

That's pretty much it what you can do in SBT. If you want to have *multi-project build configuration* and have *a plugin dependency between (sub)projects*, you don't have much choice other than what described above.

With that said, let's see if the plugin from the project `A` is accessible.

```
[plugin-project-and-another]> newTask
Hello from plugin
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 13, 2014 2:29:31 AM
[plugin-project-and-another]> B/newTask
Hello from plugin
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 13, 2014 2:29:36 AM
[plugin-project-and-another]> A/newTask
[error] No such setting/task
[error] A/newTask
[error]          ^
```

As you may have noticed, `newTask` (that comes from the plugin from the project `A`) is available in the (default) root project and the project `B`, but not in `A`.

Comment: +1 for an amazing, detailed answer that I failed to understand most of (but that's because of my sbt learning curve - when I need this, it's nice to know it's answered!)

Comment: Just ask questions when you're in trouble or doubt. The sbt community is quite vibrant so your beginner problems should be answered in secs...hopefully.

Comment: This is an example of projects/plugins.sbt when you have multiple plugins: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11777916/

Answer (score 0):

This answer may include the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754868/3189923 .

From that link, in short, set `exportJars := true` and to obtain jar file paths for a (sub)project `exportedProducts in Compile`.

Comment: Looks promising, but still doesn't solve the problem of getting `B` to depend on `A` as a plugin without making `P` depend on it

Comment: This other awnser http://stackoverflow.com/a/17904023/3189923 may address the issue as to how to lighten up dependencies/aggregation between subprojects.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the facts about plugins by side, you have a parent project P with sub-projects A and B. And then you state that A depends on P. But P is a aggregate of A and B and hence depends on A. So you already have a circular dependency between A and P. This can never work.

You have to split P in two parts: The part where A depends on (let's call this part A') and the rest (let's call this P_rest). Then you throw away P and make a new project P_rest consisting of A', A and B. And A depends on A'.

Comment: It needs to be a *plugin* dependency though, not a normal dependency, so the process you're (i think) describing wouldn't work.